# Mathjax regex finding to render it

Tags: javascript, regex, katex

I want to prerender my MathJax with KaTeX to create a pdf, I did this:

```
var re = new RegExp('<span class="math-tex">\\\((.+)\\\)\<\/span>','gmi');
var htmlR = html.replace(re, function(match, i){
    console.log(match);
    console.log(i);
    return Katex.renderToString(i);
});
```

But it's returning nothing, my string:

```
<p>En effet,&nbsp;<span style="background-color:#fff0f5"><span class="math-tex">\(P = P' - \frac{1}{2}\rho\upsilon^2((\frac{r}{r'})^4 -1)\)</span></span></p>
```

My regex is working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

Comment: Use a regex literal notation: `var re = /<span class="math-tex">\\\((.+)\\\)<\/span>/i;`. When testing at regex101, it is a good idea to grab the code from the *code generator* page.

Comment: Thank you it's working fine !